# Error while running the application for CAP Java

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We get the error while ruuning the application for my java application we are using SAP Cloud SDK :-

Error creating bean with name 'com.sap.cds.framework.spring.config.runtime.CdsRuntimeInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/CfPlatformSslContextProvider

Below is our parent Pom for for the cloud sdk

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.20.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And for the src/pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>scp-cf</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana</groupId>
        <artifactId>s4hana-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>A
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cds</groupId>
            <artifactId>cds-integration-cloud-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Can you please help me out to understand what im missing here.

Comment: Are you using our BOM correctly in your `<dependencyManagement>` section to manage SAP Cloud SDK dependencies? Please check for dependency convergence issues. Refer to: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/guides/manage-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I used the below in the main java spring boot file

```
@ComponentScan({"com.sap.cloud.sdk", <your.own.package>})
@ServletComponentScan({"com.sap.cloud.sdk", <your.own.package>})
```

Adding the dependencies in `srv/pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>scp-cf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana</groupId>
    <artifactId>s4hana-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the main parent pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.21.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It is good practice to add the BOM (`sdk-bom` here) into the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the parent pom.